# Skype for business Web SDK - Presence 'Be Right Back'

Tags: javascript, exchangewebservices, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have a problem/question about web sdk and capability.

The problem is, I have `client` ( which is similar Microsoft Skype For Business) and on the other hand as you know Microsoft Skype For Business (I call this "**native**"). When I change presence via `client` (from Online to Be Right Back), the native can understand "**yes it is be right back**" and native changes the presence to "**be right back**".

Unfortunately, when I change presence from online (or an other presence) to be right back via Native, Native keeps sending "**status = Away**". I really do not understand this. Is this a bug of Skype Web SDK or not? If you give me an answer or show the way, I would be grateful. I hope I expailed clearly the problem.

Comment: You need to post the relevant(only that part what matters to the problem) code. Otherwise, we can't help you or at least it's very hard to understand.